# Building a Python CLI: how to properly declare entry_points in setuptools.setup

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, setuptools, setup.py

### Solved using `click` instead of `argparse`, see below..

---

I'm building a **Python command line tool**, following a [great tutorial](https://medium.com/@trstringer/the-easy-and-nice-way-to-do-cli-apps-in-python-5d9964dc950d) by Thomas Stringer. My tool is used like so

```sh
$ python rsearch.py -f foo -b bar
```

I packaged it with `python setup.py sdist` and `python setup.py install`, following the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/distutils/introduction.html#distutils-simple-example). All working great! Now I install it as a `pip` package with `pip install -e .` and my executable is ready to roll, right?

```sh
$ which rsearch
/usr/local/bin/rsearch
```

#### Problem is

```sh
$ rsearch -f foo.txt -b bar/
Searching...
Searching... 
Found item from foo.txt in bar/path/to/target/
Searching...
Done!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rsearch", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('rsearch', 'console_scripts', 'rsearch')()
TypeError: main() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'foo' and 'bar'
```

I think the issue is that my `entry_points` are not specified correctly:

```py
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='rsearch',
    version='0.0.1',
    py_modules=['rsearch'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'rsearch=rsearch.__main__:main'
        ]
    })
```

Based on the tutorial I followed, albeit from 2016, this should work. I know `distutils.core` is the preferred `setup()` method for Python 3.7, but I've tried that as well and I am getting the same result.

My `__main__.py` looks like this:

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '--foo', 
    '-f',
    help='Foo help'
)
parser.add_argument(
    '--bar', 
    '-b', 
    help='Bar help'
)

def main(foi, gras):
    # code code code 
    # code code..

args = parser.parse_args()
main(args.foo, args.bar)
```

and my project is structured like this:

```
rsearch
├── rsearch
│   └── __main__.py
└── setup.py
```

Side note: the python script runs as expected:

```sh
$ python __main__.py -f foo.txt -b bar/
Searching...
Searching... 
Found item from foo.txt in bar/path/to/target/
Searching...
Done!
```

So the script doesn't appear to be the problem. This error only occurs when trying to run executable built with `setuptools.setup()`

I'm using `Python 3.7.3` and `pip 19.1.1`. Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

---

## UPDATE

Per @techouse's suggestion, I replicated this CLI using [`click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) and updated the `entry_points` assignment in `setup.py`, following their [documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/setuptools/).

```py
setup(
    name='rsearch',
    version='0.0.1',
    py_modules=['rsearch'],
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        rsearch=rsearch_script:cli
    ''',
)
```

I renamed the script to `rsearch_script.py` and used the `click` decorators instead of `argparse`:

```py
@click.command()
@click.option('--foo', '-f')
@click.option('--bar', '-b')
def cli(foo, bar):
    # code code code
    # code code..
```

I also moved the files (from the docs, might not matter)

```sh
rsearch
├── rsearch_script.py
└── setup.py
```

In this directory I ran `pip install -e .` and boom!

No errors, working.

```sh
$ rsearch -f foo.txt -b bar
Searching...
Searching...

# ...

$ rsearch --help
Usage: rsearch [OPTIONS]

Options:
  -f, --foo TEXT
  -b, --bar TEXT
  --help
```

Thanks for the tip @techouse - You were right, I'll use Click for developing Python CLIs from now on.

Comment: I would suggest using [`Click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) instead of `argparse`, simply because testing `argparse` is a pain. Then check the [docs here](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/setuptools/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @techouse, I've heard positive things about Click, it's a lovely library. I'll give it a whirl!

Answer (score 0):

The entry_points will call your `main` directly - that is the last `main` in `'rsearch=rsearch.__main__:main'`. This means that the code that calls the args parser never gets called, and hence you get the problem with the arguments never being passed in.

Don't change your `setup.py` but instead move the `args = parser.parse_args()` line under the `main` function.

The `if __name__ == __main__` condition will only be run if the script is run directly like you have done, and not in pretty much any other circumstance.

Comment: Hi dwagon, thanks for the insight! Indeed removing `if __name__` etc. from my script did fix the error, and `rsearch --help` runs now without issues. Strangely I still get this exact error when I run the script with real arguments `rsearch -f foo.txt -b bar/`. Whats odd, is this actually works, but as soon as the script finishes running, it produces the exact same `Traceback` as above..

Comment: I've updated this post based on @dwagon's response. Thanks again! Makes a lot of sense why we need to remove `if __name__ == "__main__"` for an executable, I'm just so used to doing this for Python scripting that I didn't even think twice about it.